# Is there any effect on modern SharePoint search, if we make a modern SP site as home site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, modern-experience, home-site

I want to make a modern SharePoint site as home site, would like to know is there any effect on modern SharePoint search if we do so?

Answer (score 2):

When you set up a home site, Search scope for the site will be changed to **tenant-wide search**.

**Source**: [Set up a home site in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/set-up-a-home-site-in-sharepoint-online/)

> Search for the site is scoped to all sites within the organization. Having a great search experience is critical for the success of the home site. [Learn more about Microsoft Search](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/overview-microsoft-search)

**Source**: [Set up a home site for your organization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/home-site)

Comment: Hi @sarbashis, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no effect on SharePoint modern search.

Comment: I may be mistaken. It has no effect on the overall SharePoint modern search, according to Ganesh's answer, it will affect the search scope of this site.